# SSIS Package Takes Longer Time To Complete

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I've done a migration from SQL 2008 to SQL 2014. Unfortunately, one of the SSIS package which takes only 6 hours to run on 2008 is now taking 8 hours on 2014.

Can somebody told me why this is happening and how can I solve this problem? Is it something to do with setting?

I appreciate any idea/help from you guys. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need to provide a little more detail.  What version of SQL (Express, etc.), what are you generally running or what components is your packages using, etc.

Comment: Did you migrate the databases only or the SSIS packages as well ?

Comment: Also, narrow it down to what tasks are taking longer from version to version.

Comment: Anthony, I'm using SQL Server 2014 Enterprise.

Thomas, I migrate the database and the SSIS package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be some problems:

1. Check the operating system is the same data SQL 2008.
2. Check the memory SQL SERVER:

   > Right-click:  **Server properties** -> **Memory** -> **Maximum Server Memory**
3. Sometimes the virtual team, lowers the CPU consumption for the benefit of another machine
   (If this is a virtual machine).

Answer (score 0):

What about logging?

In 2012, the concept of project deployments was born. In addition to that concept, a centralized SSIS database was created by default when as Integration Services server was installed. Are you deploying the packages to a server to be run? If so, then logging might slow you down. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231191.aspx especially if the default it set to verbose and/or you're doing your own custom logging ( for each event, two executions happen).

Your SSIS server may be drowning from the default logging in addition to the standard workload of the data movements in the package. Try turning logging down or off. Basic works well for us. While the package is executing, monitor any resources that are running too high. That could give you some hints about potential bottle necks and where else to look.